# DataGridView to Excel in reverse. With answer

Tags: c#, datagridview, nullreferenceexception

I have a datagridview that populates my excel sheet. It works fine but I needed to reverse it as in the datagridview it shows: A B C which is what I want but when I send it to excel it shows: C B A
I found other posts that had the same problem and have used the answers provided in my code. I am getting a `nullreferenceexception` but all my rows have a value. Could it be I'm picking up the blank row at the bottom of the datagridview?

```
for (int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
DataRow myRow = (row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
DatasetRead( FlagWhich, myRow, XLRowPos );

XLRowPos++;
}
```

This is where my problem is: `row.DataBoundItem` the row has the correct value but the databounditem is null. From what I could find in the other datagridview / excel posts this is due to an empty row which must be the last row. I've tried `Rows.Count - 1` but it doesn't work

This is my code reading forward:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rows)
{
DataRow myRow = (row.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
DatasetRead( FlagWhich, myRow, XLRowPos );

XLRowPos++;
}
```

This works but I need it to be the other way around.

======Answer below======

This worked for me:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in lst.AsEnumerable( ).Reverse( ))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        excelSheet.Cells[XLRowPos, i + 1] = row.Cells[i].Value.ToString( );
    }
    XLRowPos++;
}
```

Comment: It depends on if you have bound DataGridView to a Datasource already or not. it seems the binding is lost or not occurred yet.

Comment: @MostafaArmandi I may have missed something out trying to reverse it but I can't see where.

Comment: @MostafaArmandi I can reproduce the same error by manually choosing all rows including the last empty row in the going forward code.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var dataRow in dataGridView1.Rows.Reverse())
{
  DataRow myRow = (dataRow.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
  DatasetRead( FlagWhich, myRow, XLRowPos );

  XLRowPos++;
}
```

Comment: My dataGridView1.Rows. only contains Remove and RemoveAt under R. Do I need to add a using statement?

Comment: did you try : 
`for (int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i > 0; i--)`